# How can I check if value in an array in an object is more than 3 characters?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I want to implement a comments section in my app and I want to restrict each comment. The restriction should be a length of the characters for each comment that is not shorter than 3 and not longer than 150. This is my schema:

```
const ComentsSchema = new Schema({
comments: [{
    comment: { type: String , validate: checkComment},
    commentator: { type: String }
}]
```

});

Now the validation part makes a problem. When I get rid of it, app works and comments get saved in the database, but than I don't have a restriction. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code for validation:

```
let checkComment = (comment) => {
if (!comment[0]) {
    return false;
} else if (comment[0].length < 3 || comment[0].length > 150) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

};

Comment: you run `checkComment` on every comment string, so you should remove the array access `[0]` else you always access just the first character in that string which satisfies the second condition as long as the string is non empty

Comment: That is it. Comments now work as planned... Thank you